# Convert string array to 2d Array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have the following string array comprising of geo-coordinates

```
32.28057860000054 -174.8307036999996,
33.03439570061262 -174.82691533618038,
33.15555942151208 -174.8255452254468,
33.161189722126196 -174.825486109871,
33.16405200490681 -174.82544919191812,
33.22284105148913 -174.824784409563,
33.32412188155387 -174.82338459780988,
33.341040408962115 -174.8231663812863
...............
```

I want to convert the above to a 2d-array and also swap the values

e.g.

```
{
   { -174.8307036999996, 32.28057860000054 },
   { -174.82691533618038, 33.03439570061262 }
}
```

I know how to create a 2d-array from scratch

```
string[,] name = new string[,]
{
      { "damien", "kettle" },
      { "joe", "bloggs" },
      { "pat", "murphy" },
      { "tom", "jones" }
};
```

but not able to figure out how I can convert the original list of coordinates?

Suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double[,] coordinates2D = new double[coordinates.Length, 2];

for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.Length; i++)
{
    string[] parts = coordinates[i].Split(' ');
    double lat = double.Parse(parts[0]);
    double lon = double.Parse(parts[1]);
    coordinates2D[i, 0] = lon;
    coordinates2D[i, 1] = lat;
}
```

Or

```
// Split the coordinates into a jagged array of strings
string[][] splitCoordinates = coordinates.Select(c => c.Split(' ')).ToArray();

// Create a 2D array of doubles and swap the values
double[,] result = new double[splitCoordinates.Length, 2];
for (int i = 0; i < splitCoordinates.Length; i++)
{
    result[i, 0] = double.Parse(splitCoordinates[i][1]);
    result[i, 1] = double.Parse(splitCoordinates[i][0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Satyam. `double lat = double.Parse(parts[0]);` is erroring on second pass as `ThrowOverflowOrFormatException` with `Input string was not in a correct format`

Comment: double lat, lon;
    if (double.TryParse(parts[0], out lat) && double.TryParse(parts[1], out lon))
    {
        coordinates2D[i, 0] = lon;
        coordinates2D[i, 1] = lat;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work

```
var text = """
32.28057860000054 -174.8307036999996,
33.03439570061262 -174.82691533618038,
33.15555942151208 -174.8255452254468,
33.161189722126196 -174.825486109871,
33.16405200490681 -174.82544919191812,
33.22284105148913 -174.824784409563,
33.32412188155387 -174.82338459780988,
33.341040408962115 -174.8231663812863
""";

var values = text.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries | StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(l => l.Split(" "))
    .Select(a => new double[] { double.Parse(a.Last()), double.Parse(a.First())});
```